# How do I add another column to a System.Object using a list in Powershell?

Tags: object, powershell-3.0

I am making a script to query active directory via powershell and pull all computers that contain a username in the description field, then filter that list with only computers last logged in the past 14 days.

This is what I have so far:

```
$queryAD = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=West Division,DC=cable,DC=comcast,DC=com' -Properties Name, Description -Filter {(Name -like "WA*") -and (Description -like $wildCard)} | Select-Object Name, Description
$lastLogon = $queryAD | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description | %{$_.replace(("$NTname" + ";"),"").split(";")[0]} | %{get-date $_ -format d}
```

I'd like to add the list generated from `$lastLogon` to `$queryAD`, right now `$queryAD` is returning two columns with headers Name and Description. I need a third header added called Last Logon Date and contain the list in `$lastLogon`. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the values to an array of objects to make your output cleaner (if this method is providing you the data you want) like so:

```
$queryAD = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=West Division,DC=cable,DC=comcast,DC=com' -Properties Name, Description -Filter {(Name -like "WA*") -and (Description -like $wildCard)} | Select-Object Name, Description
$computer_list = @()
foreach($computer in $queryAD) {
    $computer_info = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $computer.Name
        Description = $computer.Description
        LastLogonDate = $computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description | %{$_.replace(("$NTname" + ";"),"").split(";")[0]} | %{get-date $_ -format d}
    }
    $computer_list += $computer_info
}
```

in which case `$computer_list` will contain all of the info you're gathering in tidy objects.

...but this method seems overcomplicated. Look into [this](http://blog.mattvogt.net/2011/10/06/powershell-last-logon-timestamp-for-single-ho/) blog entry by Matt Vogt for a better way to query for old machines in AD.